# Why is ゆ written in hiragana on bath houses' noren?

Tags: hiragana

I am informally teaching Japanese to friends and they sometimes ask interesting questions I can't answer.

Yesterday, I told them that ゆ could often be seen in front of public bath houses, and someone asked me why the kanji wasn't used. I guess it has been like this for centuries, so that everybody can read the sign, but I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Imagery vs. Information

Try staring at the kanji 「湯」 for 5 minutes and tell me what it enabled you to "see" and/or "imagine".  Did you have fun?

I did it before posting my answer and all I "saw" was hot water.  I had no fun staring at the kanji.  **Kanji have specific meanings and that means there is not much room for imagination**.  「湯」 means "hot water", but who ***does not*** know that a public bathhouse has hot water?

Now try staring at the hiragana 「ゆ」 for 5 minutes.  What did you see?  Maybe not much if you do not possess a large vocabulary in Japanese.

I started staring at 「ゆ」 and within 30 seconds, I was already in ゆ-topia with the nice images conjured by the kana.

I was soaking in the perfect-temperature **ゆ** very **ゆ**ったりと("relaxed") and **ゆ**っくりと("leisurely").  I obtained 心の**ゆ**とり("ease of mind").　Thank **ゆ** so much, public bathhouse!

If we have three writing systems, we might as well take advantage of each of them?  Who cares if that caused Japanese-learners confusion?  English was never an English-learner-friendly language, either!

Above is just a personal opinion of a native Japanese speaker, ゆ know.

Comment: 今年度で一番面白かったです（笑）

Comment: ゆ said it! とても面白かったわ